# How to update a struct value?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, struct, foreach, var

I have some monthly data that I need to calculate a specific value for before it gets displayed, using:

```
.onAppear{
     ForEach(monthlyTilt) {item in
          item.degrees = NewValue…        
     }
 }
```

With a Struct/var combination of:

```
struct MonthlyTilt: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var month: String
    var day: Int
    var degrees: Double
}

var monthlyTilt = [
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Jan",  day: 15,  degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Feb",  day: 46,  degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Mar",  day: 74,  degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Apr",  day: 105, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "May",  day: 135, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Jun",  day: 166, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Jul",  day: 196, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Aug",  day: 227, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Sept", day: 258, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Oct",  day: 288, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Nov",  day: 319, degrees: 0.0),
    MonthlyTilt(month: "Dec",  day: 349, degrees: 0.0)
]
```

The error message reads: Cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant. monthlyTilt is set as a var.

How can I update the degree value?

Comment: `ForEach` is used in a `View` hierarchy. You may be looking for `monthlyTilt.forEach`

Comment: Are you trying to update `degrees` after you already created each struct, or do you just want to format the existing value of `degrees` differently for display purposes. These are two different approaches.

Comment: The degrees starts with a zero value and then I want to calculate it with its correct value before the view gets displayed.

Comment: Calculate it when you change the data, not when its about to be displayed. In SwiftUI it's all about having your data prepared before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to update a `struct` which is, by default, immutable. There are a few different approaches to this. One way is to populate the `monthlyTilt` var only when you get the data you need to build the structs. You'll probably want to update your datasource to include the month and day as well.

```swift
import SwiftUI

public struct FBKChatBotView: View {
    @State private var tilts: [MonthlyTilt] = []
    
    public var body: some View {
      VStack {
        ForEach(tilts) { tilt in
          Text("Tilt is \(tilt.degrees) degrees")
        }
      }
        .onAppear {
           someDataSource() { items in
             items.forEach { item in
               let tilt = MonthlyTilt(month: item.month, day: item.day, degrees: item.degrees)
               tilts.append(tilt)
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to set up an `ObservableObject` to handle building that list of an `@Published` array of tilts and your view would update when that changed. Then you could eliminate the `onAppear`.

*Or*, you could create a `mutating` function in your struct that allows it to set/overwrite its own variables.

```swift
struct MonthlyTilt: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var month: String
    var day: Int
    var degrees: Double

    mutating func setDegrees(_ to: Double) {
       degrees = to
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but I never really like that last (`mutating`) option because it opens the door to other things also mutating the struct and then you lose the strictness of an immutable struct. I don't know if that's best practice or personal preference, but I almost always try not to make structs mutable.

*Sample code is off the top of my head so excuse any typos*